# regular expression to treat string as mutiple line in ruby

Tags: ruby, regex, ruby-on-rails-3

I am new to ruby. I am struck at a point where data needs to match a pattern. I was wondering if there is a regular expression which makes ruby to treat string as multiple lines.

Comment: It will be helpful if you can provide more detail and an example.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you are looking for the `m` option. `m` will allow `.` to match a new line.

```ruby
a = "this is my
string"
 => "this is my\nstring" 

a
 => "this is my\nstring" 

a.match /my.string/m
 => #<MatchData "my\nstring"> 

a.match /not my.string/m
 => nil
```